# Univariate feature selection in caret

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

I would like to select features based on anovaScores in caret. I can get the scores by `scores <- apply(train_data, 2, anovaScores, train_data$target)` and then sort features and select n best ones, but I don't know how to do it with sbfControl. In documentation to anovaScores is written: "The functions described here are passed to the algorithm via the functions argument of sbfControl."

Doing

```
  featSel_ctrl <- sbfControl(functions = anovaScores)
  featSel <- sbf(target ~., data=train_data, sbfControl = featSel_ctrl)
```

doesn't work. Will produce 'object of type 'closure' is not subsettable' error.

Answer (score 0):

`functions` has other elements that you are excluding. See the [documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/filters.html#syntax) that has some details. If you are doing classification, `anovaScores` is already being used.

Comment: Can you expand this answer with code specific to the situation of the OP?